# Invoke Func with unknown return type

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I'm trying to invoke the Func below, but I'd like the ??? part of it to be filled in at the moment of invoking.

```
    public void Publish(string topic)
    {
        ...

        // 'actions' is a List of delegates, defined as List<Delegate>

        for (int i = 0; i < actions.Count; i++)
        {
            ((Func<???>)actions[i])(); // Invokation
        }

        ...
    }
```

Actions are added as such:

```
    public void Subscribe<T>(string topic, Func<T> action)
    {
        ...

        actions.Add(action);

        ...
    }
```

Thing is I don't know what ??? is going to be (hence my question). Might be a boolean, string, int, ... How do I go about doing this? Can I somehow base this on the return type of the action to invoke?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please also the code, where `actions` are populated ? Thanks

Comment: What do you intend to do with the return value of the delegate?

Comment: If you invoke the action the way shown in your code, i.e. ``((Func<???>)actions[i])()``, the return type is ``void`` (because you are not using the result of the action), and you should use ``IList<Action>`` as the type of the ``actions`` IList. Also, in that case you do not need to cast anything when invoking the action, i.e. ``actions[i]()`` will be enough.

Comment: At the moment I don't intend to do anything with the actual return type of the delegates, they merely need to be invoked.
The functions that will be added as the actions in the Subscribe method, have no parameters but can have any return type.

Comment: Use `actions[i].DynamicInvoke(null)`, see if that does what you want. Question: Do you *need* the return type at all? You call the parameter `action`, what is the return value? It seems you're going to ignore it, why do you have it?

Comment: That does indeed seem to work, thanks! As for the actions that are to be invoked, i.e. the actual methods, they were not written by me so I have no say over how they're implemented.

Comment: The thing is, if a method returns something, you are likely supposed to use that return value for something. You should question your design, as ignoring the return value might lead to undesired behaviour…

Comment: You certainly have a point and probably something will have to be done with those return values, though that is another matter in and of itself. Thanks to everyone that chimed in!

Answer (score -1):

So, eventually managed to solve it using [Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v%C3%A5gs%C3%A6ther-karlsen) comment above. So instead of

```
((Func<???>)actions[i])();
```

I called the action by writing

```
actions[i].DynamicInvoke(null);
```

which called the delegate correctly.